# Return amount of times a number is greater than previous number in a list

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to inspect a list from user input and determine which numbers are greater than the previous number. I can do this fine with a given list and a simple for loop

```
lst = [2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 5, 9]
count = 0

for n in range(1, len(lst)):   
    if lst[n] > lst[n-1]:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

but unable to make it work when specifying user input. I'm attempting to use a while loop which ends with an input of 0

```
lst = []
count = 0
finished = False

while not finished:
    n = int(input())
    if n != 0:
        lst.append(n)
        for i in range(0, len(lst)): 
            if lst[i] > lst[i-1]:
                count += 1
    else:
        finished = True
print(count)
```

The for loop works on its own and appending the input in to the list works, but I'm wanting to know why when combining the two the code does not return the correct number

Comment: if you're only comparing the last input, you don't really need a list do you?

Comment: Check the `range` on your second snippet compared the the first, and you may find the issue.

Comment: @Chris great point, he should just need to store the previous number, and if the current input is greater then increase his counter. Should help the runtime a lot.

Comment: Not to mention, you don't reset the counter each time you iterate over the list in your current code. if I have [1,2,3], that `count` is 2, but if the next input in 4, then your code goes "[1,2,3,4] - let me increase the counter 3 times!" so the final count is 5, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your code lies within the fact that the whole list `lst` is iterated over entirely every time a new input is given.

If you build the list first using your while loop and then count the amount of numbers that are greater than their predecessor within that list after should yield the correct result.

```py
lst = []
count = 0
finished = False

while not finished:
    n = int(input())
    if n != 0:
        lst.append(n)
        
    else:
        finished = True

for i in range(0, len(lst)): 
    if lst[i] > lst[i-1]:
        count += 1


print(count)
```

You would be better off if you didn't store the input in a list but simply store the last input and compare it against the new input. Then you could increment your counter accordingly.

```py
count = 0
finished = False
last = None
current = None

while not finished:
    n = int(input())
    if n != 0:
        last = current
        current = n
        
        if last != None and current > last:
            counter += 1
            
    else:
        finished = True
```